# discord ActionRow is not JSON serializable

Tags: discord, discord.py, components

I am trying to have a single message with multiple action rows, each with 5 or less buttons in. By looking at the docs, this seems right but clearly it is not.

I have the button list there for an alternative way that also doesn't work so I am aware that it's useless here.

```py
# Sends a message with all the days of the week in
await message.channel.send("Days of the week.")
# Message per category
actionRowOfRows = ActionRow()
buttonRow = []
fill = 0
for day in ["Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"]:  # For role in category
    if fill < 5:
        buttonRow.append(Button(style=ButtonStyle.blue, custom_id=day,label=day)) # New button in existing buttonRow
        fill += 1
    else:
        actionRowOfRows.append(ActionRow(buttonRow)) # Adds row to the row of rows
        buttonRow = []
        buttonRow.append(Button(style=ButtonStyle.blue, custom_id=day,label=day)) # New button in the blank buttonRow
        fill=0


# Add button to message per day
category_message = await message.channel.send(content="The week", components=actionRowOfRows)
```

`TypeError: Object of type ActionRow is not JSON serializable` is thrown by encoder.py after going through the discord_componenets library.

Full Error:

````
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "S:\Documents\test.py", line 179, in on_message
    category_message = await message.channel.send(content="The week", components=actionRowOfRows)
  File "C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\discord_components\client.py", line 48, in send_component_msg_prop
    return await self.send_component_msg(ctxorchannel, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\discord_components\client.py", line 177, in send_component_msg
    data = await self.bot.http.request(
  File "C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 156, in request
    kwargs['data'] = utils.to_json(kwargs.pop('json'))
  File "C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\discord\utils.py", line 328, in to_json
    return json.dumps(obj, separators=(',', ':'), ensure_ascii=True)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\json\__init__.py", line 234, in dumps
    return cls(
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\json\encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\json\encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\json\encoder.py", line 179, in default
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type ActionRow is not JSON serializable```
````

Comment: The code you sent is pretty long/ specific. Have you tried simplifying the problem to indentify the issue? The issue seems to be that you try to save an actionrow in a json, which wont work as its a class and you cant save classes in a json file. However you snippet doesnt include any json saving code, thus the error comes from somewhere else in your script.

Comment: The error comes from the discord_components library. I can simplify the code to make it more clear though.

Comment: can you give the full error?

Comment: one thing i notice is that you seem to add actionrows to the actionrow, which according to the discord api docs isnt allowed

Comment: I personally havent messed around with buttons, but i think (educated guess while looking at the api docs, as buttons arent in the discordpy docs yet it seems) that you need to make a list[] of actionrows and pass that to the components key while sending

Comment: I have tried doing a list of action rows and that produces the same result unfortunately.

Comment: What you can try doing is not using an actionrow and just using a two dimensional array as suggested here https://devkiki7000.gitbook.io/discord-components/guide/frequently-asked-questions#how-to-make-buttons-inline

Comment: Same error with the 2D array of buttons

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same struggle where I needed to put 5 buttons on each row. I don't know what exactly is wrong with your code, but I would like to post my solution to the problem.

```
    await message.channel.send("Days of the week.")
    # Message per category
    buttons = [[]]

    for day in ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday",
                "Sunday"]:  # For role in category
        if len(buttons[-1]) > 4:
            buttons.append([])

        buttons[-1].append(Button(style=ButtonStyle.blue, custom_id=day, label=day))  # New button in the blank buttonRow


    # Add button to message per day
    category_message = await message.channel.send(content="The week", components=buttons)
```